# How to handle nested structs in templates in generated reflection code

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to make a C++ reflection library. The goal is to use clang parser to generate a bunch of Meta data from header files to create meta header files that can be included in order to do certain reflective operations. I've used a Meta_data class that gets specialized for each type in the header file, and it works pretty well for concrete types, but it fails for nested structs within template types.

Here's an example:

```cpp
// header.h
struct foo
{
  int member1;
  int member2;
  struct nested
  {
    int member;
  };
};

template <int val>
struct template_foo
{
  int member;
  struct nested
  {
    int member;
  };
};

// meta/header.h

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
template <typename T>
struct Meta_data
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) != 0, "Must be specialized");
};

template <>
struct Meta_data<foo>
{
  constexpr auto tuple_view(foo& object)
  {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(object.member1, object.member2);
  }
};

template <>
struct Meta_data<foo::nested>
{
  constexpr auto tuple_view(foo::nested& object)
  {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(object.member);
  }
};

template <int val>
struct Meta_data<template_foo<val>>
{
  constexpr auto tuple_view(template_foo<val>& object)
  {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(object.member);
  }
};

// This fails 
//
// template <int val>
// struct Meta_data<typename template_foo<val>::nested>
// {
//   constexpr auto tuple_view(template_foo<val>::nested& object)
//   {
//     return std::forward_as_tuple(object.member);
//   }
// };
//
//
// GCC 10.2.0 Error output
// test.cpp:56:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
//    56 | struct Meta_data<typename template_foo<val>::nested>
//       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// test.cpp:56:8: note:         ‘val’

// test.cpp
int main()
{
  
}
```

I understand the compiler error, but I can't think of a different way to get this to work. The goal is to be able to take any type and view its members as a tuple, likeso:

```cpp
std::get<0>(Meta_data<some_struct>::tuple_view(some_struct_instance));
```

Is there a way to redesign my Meta_class so that I can get the desired end behavior, even for nested structs within templated structs/classes?

Comment: Things like this have been attempted poorly for decades. The example most familiar to me is Qt's Meta-Object-Compiler. There's no good way to solve this generally without compiler support. It is why proper reflection must be a language feature and several smart C++ people are pushing to standardize it.

Comment: Compiler plugins are pretty useful for that and I, personally, have tried those in the past. It definitely works, but amount of effort needed to get it right is very, very substantial.